# Magento create new separate search result page

Tags: magento

We have created a brand "micro site" within our main Magento site by using a category custom design change. There is a search tool on the page that performs a search and directs to the search results page. The issue is that the search results are displayed in the main sites colors etc.

So we need to be able to set a design change for the search results page depending on where it has originated from.

Any thoughts on how best to achieve this?